# Dealing with other dependencies in your own Maven dependency

Tags: dependency-management, maven

Maybe this question is a duplicate. However, I could not find a suitable article in my research. If you know an informative, comprehensive article about this topic, please send it to me.

I want to reuse and centralize the utils I created for my Spring REST API for my future projects. That's why I thought I'd outsource them to my own project and make them available as a Maven dependency.

These Util files e.g. a basic service, basic controllers also contain Spring annotations, i.e. I need some Spring dependencies in my Util dependency. Now I'm a bit unsure whether I'm making a mistake or not.

First of all, I'm not sure if I should even use spring dependencies in a utility dependency or try to remove everything. Otherwise, I'll have to specify a spring version, but it might differ from the version I want to use later in the project it's included in.  How am I supposed to solve this?